# Interactive plot Chaco, Exception occurred in traits notification

Tags: python, enthought, chaco

I'm working with Chaco library. I make an interactive plot and in this plot, with chaco.tools.api RangeSelection, I can select a part of this. Now, I like know in what posision is this rectangle. With the follow code I can do all what I need, but I have the following error, why?? In the error, the points to I nedd are the selection_masks

This is the code:

```
# Major library imports
from numpy import arange
from scipy.special import jn

# Enthought library imports
from enable.api import Component, ComponentEditor
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, Any, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import Item, Group, View

# Chaco imports
from chaco.api import create_line_plot, add_default_axes, add_default_grids
from chaco.tools.api import RangeSelection, RangeSelectionOverlay

# # Create the Chaco plot.
def _create_plot_component(self):

    numpoints = 100
    low = -5
    high = 15.001
    x = arange(low, high, (high-low)/numpoints)

    # Plot a bessel function
    y = jn(0, x)
    plot = create_line_plot((x,y), color=(0,0,1,1), width=2.0, index_sort="ascending")
    plot.active_tool = RangeSelection(plot, left_button_selects = True,     auto_handle_event = False)
    plot.overlays.append(RangeSelectionOverlay(component=plot))
    plot.bgcolor = "white"
    plot.padding = 50
    add_default_grids(plot)
    add_default_axes(plot)
    self.times_ds = plot.index
    self.times_ds.on_trait_change(self._selections_changed, 'metadata_changed')

    return plot

# Attributes to use for the plot view.
size=(600,500)
title="Simple line plot"

class Demo(HasTraits):
    times_ds = Any()
    plot = Instance(Component)
    corr_renderer = Any()

    traits_view = View(
                    Group(
                        Item('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(size=size),
                             show_label=False),
                        orientation = "vertical"),
                    resizable=True, title=title,
                    width=size[0], height=size[1]
                    )

    def _plot_default(self):
         return _create_plot_component(self)

    def _selections_changed(self, event):
        selections = event["selections"]
        low, high = selections
        print low, high

demo = Demo()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.configure_traits()
```

And this is part of the error (in the error are the point of the rectangle to I nedd)

```
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object:   <chaco.array_data_source.ArrayDataSource object at 0x66a94d0>, trait: metadata_changed, old  value: <undefined>, new value: True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/franco/Python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits/trait_notifiers.py", line 521, in rebind_call_1
    self.dispatch( getattr( obj(), self.name ), new )
  File "/home/franco/Python/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits/trait_notifiers.py", line 455, in dispatch
handler( *args )
  File "/home/franco/Desktop/Proyecto/Codigo/analisis_mas_range_relections.py", line 59, in _selections_changed
    selections = event["selections"]
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object:  <chaco.array_data_source.ArrayDataSource object at 0x66a94d0>, trait: metadata_changed, old  value: <undefined>, new value: True

#the error continue but is the same error change the selection_masks....

TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object:  <chaco.array_data_source.ArrayDataSource object at 0x6758290>, trait: metadata_changed, old  value: <undefined>, new value: {'selection_masks': (-0.5953709619238516, 10.991581102204394)}

#the selection_masks are the point to I need
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is the code that you ran. There is no line in the code that you posted that corresponds to the line in the first traceback: `corr_index = self.corr_renderer.index`. Can you clarify what is going on here?

Comment: Robert, I put an error of old code. I edit my questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the first traceback is coming from since it appears to quote code that is not posted here. However, the second traceback is clear.

The `metadata_changed` `Event` does not get assigned the dictionary of metadata. Or at least, not always. The Tools that modify the metadata have been inconsistently written over the years. Just grab the metadata dictionary directly from the data source instead.

Comment: Robert, I'm a very new user in Chaco, and I can't understan well about metadata dictionary. Where can I reed about this?? or where can I see some examples?? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `self.times_ds.metadata` is the metadata dictionary that you need to look at. Just use that instead of `event` in your `_selections_changed()` method (which you can change to be argumentless). The metadata dictionary will have a `'selections'` entry that contains what you want to look at.

Comment: Thanls Robert for your help. To run the above code just change the following `sel_indices = self.times_ds.metadata.get('selections', [])` in `def _selections_changed(self):`

Comment: 1 Question more. Who can I do to metadata dictionary write in key which I want? and not in `selections`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot parse that question. Are you asking how to make the `RangeSelection` write to a different key than the default `'selections'`? Set its `metadata_name` trait to the key that you want.